# static ip spring boot heroku quotaguard

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have a spring boot application deployed using Heroku. I have a google cloud database and for security I need to add a whitelist of Ips in database. For this, I need a static IP. I was trying to use QuotaGuard an add on of Heroku. But I need to put spring boot application behind a proxy and I tried setting system variables:

```java
@Bean
fun initProxy(){
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", proxyUser);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", proxyPassword);
}
```

But It seems It does not work. Have someone done it before? or what do you suggest me? I need a fast and efficient solution.

Thanks you